# How to send an array as param from smarty template in javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters, smarty

Problem description:

I have an Array($all_article_data) in a .tpl File with 200 items.
 Now I want to send this array as Param in a javascript function.

`<span onclick="on('{$all_article_data}')">Example</span>`

JAVASCRIPTFUNCTION

```
function on(data){
     alert(data);
}
```

And I recive in text "array" :( To see if there is something in this array i used:

```
function on(data) {
   var i;
   for(i=0 ; i<=data.length; i++){
       alert(data[i]);
   }
}
```

This shows in differents alerts  a    r    r   a   y
I need to manipulate this array in javascript and create a table with the 
values.

Thanks for Tipps

Best regards

Comment: you are receiving `'array'` because you are passing a string in the function instead of an object. Simply call it as `<span onclick="on({$all_article_data})">Example</span>` without the quotes.

Comment: Thanks vikscool: I have in the alert windos this Message "function Array() { [native code] }" Do you know what's now the problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use php's `json_encode` on your array:

```
$encoded= json_encode($all_article_data);

<span onclick="on('{$encoded}')">Example</span>
```

Then in your javascript, parse it back:

```
let jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
```

You can then use `jsonData` as you intend.

Comment: Thanks Stuart for the answer, i've already tried with json_encode und JSON.parse just this time i've tried with a :    `let jsonData = JSON.parse(data)` and not with `var jsonData = JSON.parse(data)`    Now is not showed the alert windows. Do you know if json string can be showed in alert? Thanks in advance

Comment: Indeed a json string can be alerted. Depending on where you alert is, jsonData might not be in scope (as its declared with let). Try using var instead for now and see if you get your data alerted.

Comment: With var a have the same Problem, the alert window is not showed :(

Comment: Could you post your php array, or the contents of json_encode(your_array) please

Comment: array(103) {
  [0] => array(10) {
    [0] => string(7) "SW10001"
    [1] => string(38) "Cashew Kerne gerostet und gesalzen BIO"
    [2] => string(0) ""
    [3] => NULL
    [4] => string(4) "7777"
    [5] => string(0) ""
    [6] => string(0) ""
    [7] => string(0) ""
    [8] => string(0) ""
    [9] => string(0) ""
    [10] => string(0) ""
  }
  [1] => array(10) {...i have 103 items

Comment: string(19152) "[["SW10001","Cashew Kerne gerostet und gesalzen BIO","",null,"7777","","","","","","","","","sw10001",null,null,null,null,null,"","",""],["SW10002","Cashew Kerne gerostet","",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],....